# Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http version 3.0.0.0 Conflict with 2.2.0.0

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I need to create an IAuthorizationFilter in my application, which is targeting .NET Core 3.0.

I needed a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext`.  That lives in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace.

When I added the NuGet for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`, I got an error saying that assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions' with version 3.0.0.0 conflicted with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions' with version 2.2.0.0.

When I looked, the NuGet I installed was version 2.2.0.  But the problem is that there is not one for version 3.0 on NuGet.

**How can I get a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext` using .NET Core 3.0?**

Comment: Which template type are using for your project?

Comment: The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` are referenced automatically now when your target framework is `netcoreapp3.0`. You will also need to make sure you are not referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in you project file any longer. Unless you are using Razor pages, then you will need a Framework Reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` instead of a Package Reference. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add a normal assembly reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.

I also needed to add the NuGet Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a framework reference to asp.net core. See the migration guide docs for details  [See the migration guide docs for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference)

Answer (score 4):

In your .csproj file, replace

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="..." />
```

with

```xml
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework)

and

> A large number of NuGet packages aren't produced for ASP.NET Core 3.0. Such package references should be removed from your project file.

from [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references)

This is needed for all these packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
- Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers